# Linq groupby on two properties

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have a list of orders. Each order have a reference to the customer and the product they bought. Like so:

```
class Orders 
{
    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
}
```

I want to group all orders where different customers have the same set of products are in the same group.

- Customer 1 - Product 1&2
- Customer 2 - Product 1&2&3
- Customer 3 - Product 1&2
- Customer 4 - Product 3&4&5

In this case, the orders for customer 1&3 will be in the same group, and orders for 2&4 will have their own group.

Is this possible to achieve with LINQ? I started with trying to group by the `CustomerId`, but am at a lost on how to proceed from there.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that their could be any number of products per customer (your example sort of suggests there may only be two products per customer).

Comment: Jason, yes any number of products per customer is possible. Will edit the question now to reflect this.

Comment: @Nait How would you expect it to be grouped then?  As more products are added/removed, wouldn't this change the groupings constantly?  I might not be understanding what you're trying to accomplish, but this seems a little off to me.

Comment: What if customer 1 has three orders with a duplicate: Product 1&2&1
Should that group with Customer 2 if his orders are: Product 1&2  ?

Comment: @David I'm retrieving the orders from a database and creating an outfile based on the data. Products are not added/removed during this.

Comment: @Cory There are no duplicates in my case.

Comment: @Nait this is true NOW.  Are you saying you can guarantee that there will be no duplicates ever?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having:

```
List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();

orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 1, ProductId = 1 });
orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 1, ProductId = 2 });
orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 2, ProductId = 2 });
orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 2, ProductId = 3 });
orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 3, ProductId = 1 });
orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 3, ProductId = 2 });
orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 4, ProductId = 3 });
orders.Add(new Orders { CustomerId = 4, ProductId = 4 });
```

LINQ Query:

```
 var groupedCustomers = 
         orders.GroupBy(i => i.CustomerId)
               .Select(i => new { CUSTOMER = i.Key, 
                                  ORDERS = i.Select(j => j.ProductId)
                                            .OrderBy(j => j)
                                          //.Distinct() to ignore duplicate orders
                                            .ToArray() })
               .ToList();

 var result = groupedCustomers.GroupBy(i => i.ORDERS, new IntArrayComparer()).ToList();
```

And here is the comparer.

```
 public class IntArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
 {    
     public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
     {
         return x.SequenceEqual(y);
     }

     public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
     {
         return base.GetHashCode();
     }
 }
```

**EDIT:** If you are looking for smarter `GetHashCode` function, you may try something like this:

```
public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
{
    return string.Join(",", obj.Select(i => i.ToString())).GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: What if customer 1 has three orders with a duplicate: Product 1&2&1 Should that group with Customer 2 if his orders are: Product 1&2 ? If they should still be in the same group, I believe you would need a `.Distinct()` in there after you select the ProductIds for each customer.

Comment: I'm not sure if the hash function is valid. Two different arrays with the same contents should have the same hash (order independent), but I think it doesn't? http://csharppad.com/gist/8068d2183d4d6624cf61

Comment: @Cory He didn't say whether they must be in the same group or not and I think it was not the main concern of this question, but anyway as you know he could use the `Distinct()` function if he wants to ignore duplicate orders.

Comment: You should use something smarter for `GetHashCode`. Now you just return the same value for any array. Although it valid (two equal arrays have equal hash code), but it means the hash table algorithm, used by `GroupBy`, degenerates to linear search.